# How to increase screen resolution

Tags: 14.04, display, display-resolution, lts

My screen is 1280 by 800, but I'd like to use a resolution of 1440 by 900.  I understand that this will result in a loss of pixels, but I don't care.  How can I add another resolution option for 1440 by 900?

[image: Screen Display Settings]

Comment: does you screen support that resolution?

Comment: my screen has 1280 pixels across and 800 pixels up but i can make it go higher than that with Windows XP which makes some pixels not visible but I don't care about that and I know I can do it I just want to know how

Answer (score 0):

Found this option and it did what I wanted - It scaled everything down so its as if I increased the resolution but without the pixel loss.

[image]